# Dropdown list in a ngFor only displaying for first list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, dropdown

I am working on a side menu which will display a list of items all with a checkbox next to each item and when the checkbox is checked --- the chevron icon will be enabled to allow the user to display a dropdown list for that checked item.

My current problem is anytime i click on the icon to expand my dropdown for the checked item... it only expands the dropdown for the first item in the list. It doesn't seem to show the dropdown for each selected item.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let item of list">
        <div class="content-col">

          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" (click)="action(item, $event);" [checked]="item.checked">
             <span class="text-body">{{item.title}}</span>
          </label>

          <button [disabled]="!item.checked" data-toggle="collapse" data-collapse-icon="ChevronDown" data-expand-icon="ChevronUp" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="listCollapse" href="#listCollapse">
                            <i class="win-icon"></i>
           </button>
           
        </div>
        
        <ul class="collapse" id="listCollapse">
          <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a role="menuitem" [routerLink]="[...]">DD 1</a>
          </li>
          <li routerLinkActive="active">
            <a [routerLink]="[...]" role="menuitem">DD 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can i make this work so i would have the collapsed dropdown list show for each of the list items when clicking on the expand icon within the for loop?

For a visual this is how i have my list:

[x] Item 1     ^
     dd a
     dd b
[x] Item 2     (down chevron)
[x] Item 3     (down chevron)

Clicking on the chevron for either items 1,2 or 3 - it only expands the dropdown for item 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue will be with the Id you are using 'listCollapse'. Because for all the list item generating with ngFor will have same id. Hence whenever triggering, the first element which have the id 'listCollapse' will be open.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the item id instead to make it more unique? like `item.id`

Comment: Yep, that is possible. but not sure about this.
`aria-controls="listCollapse" href="#listCollapse"`

Comment: i know i can do this: `[attr.aria-controls]="item.id"` but i will have do some research on binding on href.

Comment: instead of href, you can try `data-target`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below.

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
        <div class="content-col">

          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" (click)="updateItem(item, $event);" [checked]="item.checked">
            <span class="text-body">{{item.title}}</span>
          </label>

          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-collapse-icon="ChevronDown" *ngIf="item.checked == true" data-expand-icon="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-expanded="false" href="#listCollapse{{i}}">
            <button>
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </a>

          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-collapse-icon="ChevronDown" *ngIf="item.checked == false" data-expand-icon="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-expanded="false" href="null">
            <button [disabled] ="!item.checked" >
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="listCollapse{{i}}">
          <div routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a role="menuitem">DD 1</a>
          </div>
          <div routerLinkActive="active">
            <a role="menuitem">DD 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### TS

```
export class AppComponent {

list: any =
    [{
      'id': 1,
      'title': 'first',
      'checked': false
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'title': 'second',
      'checked': false
    }];

 updateItem(item: any,evento: any) {

    item.checked = !item.checked

  }

}
```

[image]